# Windows Libraries "This network location can't be included because it is not indexed" even though it IS indexed

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, search

We have a Users volume on a Server 2008 failover cluster, and we want each user to have their folder on that volume included in their Windows 7 Documents Library. When we try to add the folder, the client gives the error "This network location can't be included because it is not indexed." But it is. Or it should be...

On both servers in the cluster, we have the Windows Search Service role service installed and the services snap-in shows it is started. On the server that is sharing out Users, I've checked Indexing Options control panel, and it *is* an included location.

This seems like it should be trivial, so I'm thinking this might be an oddity that crops up only when using Windows Search on clustered servers. Is there a fix, or at least a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

And of course, after days of messing with this, we find the cause of the problem an hour after I go here for help. Hopefully my experience can help save someone else the same difficulty.

The search service was installed on both nodes, but had been set to index the Users volume when it was running on node 1. At some point, we had failed over to node 2. The search service on node 2 was configured to index Users, but I noticed that node 1's index contained about 2,000,000 items and node 2's only contained 80,000! We're not sure what caused the service to not work, but when I removed & re-added the Users volume, it began indexing Users and our clients were able to add their folders to the Library.

So the question is now "how do you get Windows Search to failover gracefully (or at all) in a Server 2008 cluster?" I'll ask that in a new thread...

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Open the library's XML configuration file and edit the location in manually. [More details available in this answer.](https://serverfault.com/questions/132658#132692)